# How to pause execution of a batch script while another batch script is running in a different server?

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I have [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) `a.bat` in `server A`, and [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) `b.bat` in `server B`.

`a.bat` calls `b.bat` using [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic).

Now the problem is, execution of `a.bat` does not wait for `b.bat` to complete and this affects the result of the consecutive command present in `a.bat`.

This is the command I have in `a.bat` *(from `server A`)*, which calls `b.bat`, *(from server B)*:

```
WMIC /NODE:"<IP of server A>" /user: <user ID> /password: <password> process call create "<path to b.bat in server B>\b.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nearly unknown command [waitfor](https://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html).

In `a.bat` wait for a signal:

```
WMIC /NODE:"<IP of server A>" /user: <user ID> /password: <password> process call create "<path to b.bat in server B>\b.bat"
waitfor "ClientReady"
echo Client is ready.
```

In `b.bat` send a signal:

```
rem do what's to do
waitfor /si "ClientReady"
```

`waitfor /si signal` sends the signal to all computers in the network (until declared otherwise), and `waitfor signal` just waits for the signal to arrive (indefinitely, until declared otherwise) See `waitfor /?` for options and switches.

Note: the signal name is case sensitive.

For testing, you don't need two computers, two `cmd` windows on the same computer works too (they`re in the same network by default)

I strongly suggest the `/t`imeout switch, should `b.bat` fail.  When timed out, the `%errorlevel%` will be `1`, else `0`

Comment: Thanks! It serves the purpose. But my question is, what if I do not specify any user in the command? Does it take the user ID which has been used to schedule the batch file in Task Scheduler?

Comment: I tested this command successfully from command prompt. However, while running the scripts with the 'waitfor' commands in ithem (one sending the signal and the other receiving it), it fails. Script a.bat is executed -> the script launches the script b.bat -> a.bat waits for a signal from b.bat -> b.bat is executed successfully -> But a.bat does not receive the signal and moves to second line with timeout error (as I have used /T with 'waitfor' cmd)

Comment: works fine for me - both on two `cmd` windows at the same computer and with two computers within the same network. Sure, `a.bat` is already waiting when `b.bat` sends the signal? Try a `timeout 1` in `b.bat` before sending the signal.

Comment: I have given a timeout of 30 seconds and a.bat does wait for the signal. Meanwhile, b.bat is supposed to send the signal but it does not. It also does not print out anything in the log (added a logger in b.bat). Hence waitfor cmd in a.bat moves to second line after waiting for 30 seconds.

This is only happening while running the scripts. But I was able to test it successfully manually from command prompt. has this issue anything to do with user ID (running a.bat logging in with my credential but launching b.bat from a.bat using a different account)

Comment: afaik, signaling does not depend on account. But it concerns me, that `b.bat` "does not print out anything in the log". There is a log entry before sending the signal?

Comment: Yes, commands before the 'waitfor' do write out into the log file. But the waitfor command does not write out anything to the log file. That's happening only when I launch a.bat (which, in turn, calls b.bat). But this is not the case if I execute b.bat directly (in that case, it does send the signal to the other server and write out info to the log file).

Comment: `waitfor /si Signal` should return a "Success" message on STDOUT. Have you tried `... >file.log 2>&1` to include STDERR to the output? If yes, what does it say?